# div vs span, ¿cuándo utilizar uno u otro?

Tags: html

Recién me estoy interiorizando y aprendiendo programación web y me urge una duda.

Entiendo que los elementos `<div>` sirven para agrupar todo tipo de elementos, lo que no logro terminar de comprender es el funcionamiento de `<span>`. Entiendo que sirve para agrupar elementos en línea, pero por ejemplo yo puedo modificar un pedazo de texto dentro de un elemento en bloque.

Entonces mi pregunta es: el contenido de un elemento en bloque, ¿es un elemento en línea o solo es contenido?

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 esto clasifica como pregunta para respuesta canónica, hay conceptos básicos que se han desarrollado en las respuestas. En desacuerdo con la aproximación que sugieres al OP

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia va a ser semántica más que técnica.

Si uno revisa la definición de `<span>` en [documentación oficial confiable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), puede ver que dice

> is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate

Es decir, que sirve para poner enunciados que no representan nada particular en la estructura del documento HTML. Se puede usar para aplicarle estilos a algo o para contener un texto que, digamos, tiene un idioma particular respecto del resto del contenido.

```css
span.ingredient {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<p>Add the <span class="ingredient">basil</span>, <span class="ingredient">pine nuts</span> and <span class="ingredient">garlic</span> to a blender and blend into a paste.</p>

<p>Gradually add the <span class="ingredient">olive oil</span> while running the blender slowly.</p>
```

Por su naturaleza genérica, no debería usarse más que cuando no aplica ningún otro elemento semántico. Como quien dice, si no es una sección, encabezado, título, tabla,... va dentro de un span.

La siguiente frase en la documentación es clave

> `<span>` is very much like a `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element.

Es decir que el div arranca usualmente en una nueva línea,

```css
.warning {
    border: 10px ridge #f00;
    background-color: #ff0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.test {
    border: 3px ridge #0f0;
    background-color: #230;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.warning img {
    width: 100%;
}

.warning p {
    font: small-caps bold 1.2rem sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="warning">
    <img src="/media/examples/leopard.jpg"
         alt="An intimidating leopard.">
    <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <img src="/media/examples/leopard.jpg"
         alt="An intimidating leopard.">
    <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
```

Mientras tanto, el span no interrumpe "el renglón" (si ignoramos los estilos, digamos). Como el div puede acomodarse como tú le digas respecto al elemento padre, a la ventana, etc., es un elemento block-level. El span no debería tener posicionamientos respecto de la ventana ni de nadie porque su uso adecuado implica que está sujeto a los estilos aplicados al contenedor donde esté (un div, un td, un section, etc.)

(Ejemplos adaptados desde la página de MDN)

Comment: Cómo hacemos? Hace 10 minutos estamos escribiendo **casi** lo mismo xd

Comment: @Mateo somos geniales, es lo que hay :P

Comment: Que el público decida entonces

Comment: Aah la vieja y confiable MDN, nunca falla

Answer (score 2):

Según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) de Mozilla:

> The <span> HTML element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate. **<span> is very much like a <div> element, but <div> is a block-level element whereas a <span> is an inline element.**

En español, la parte de nuestro interés:

> <span> es muy parecido a <div>, pero <div> es un elemento de nivel de bloque mientras que <span> es un elemento en línea.

En principio ambos son elementos muy genéricos y sirven como contenedores y para aplicar estilos.

La sutil diferencia que describe la documentación se ve mejor en un ejemplo.

Este es un ejemplo tomado de la misma página ligeramente modificado:

```css
.ingredient {
    color: #f00;
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
Con span:

<p>Add the <span class="ingredient">basil</span>, <span class="ingredient">pine nuts</span> and <span class="ingredient">garlic</span> to a blender and blend into a paste.</p>

Con div:

<p>Gradually add the <div class="ingredient">olive oil</div>

 while running the blender slowly.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A manera sencilla:

Los elementos div se usan para agrupar bloques grandes; por ejemplo; tu web necesita tener un header, un footer y un container, para dividir estos contenidos la mayoría de las ocaciones se usan **div**'s.

```
<div class="header">
   ...
</div>
<div class="main_content">
   ...
</div>
<div class="footer">
   ...
</div>
```

Ahora los span; imagina que en tu página web trata de recetas de cómida; tienes una lista de ingredientes y quieres resaltar una parte del texto para decirle al usuario que es importante. 3 cucharadas de azúcar glass.
Si lo que se quiere resaltar es "azúcar glass" para que las personas no se equivoquen con azúgar simple, ahí puedes usar **span** para resaltar ese pequeño detalle.

```
<div class="lista">
   <ul>
      <li> Una taza de leche</li>
      <li> Medio queso</li>
      <li> 3 cucharadas de <span class="text_important">azúcar glass</span></li>
      ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

El ejemplo muestra como estoy dividiendo la lista en un bloque por separada, el div divide la lista del resto del código. El span simplemente se usar para darle estilo a algo en concreto.

No se si me expliqué bien, pero aquí te dejo este enlace en el que explican un poco más a detalle la diferencia: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-div-and-span-tag-in-html/

Answer (score 1):

- div es un [elemento de bloque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements)
- span es un [elemento en línea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Inline_elements).

Esto significa que para usarlos semánticamente, los **divs** deben usarse para envolver secciones de un documento, mientras que los **span** deben usarse para envolver pequeñas porciones de texto, imágenes, etc.

Por ejemplo un buen uso sería:

```
<div>¡Esta podría ser una gran división principal con contenido relevante y de extensión considerable en cuanto a código se refiere, con <span>un poco</span> de texto dividido!</div>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que es **ilegal/incorrecto** colocar un elemento a nivel de bloque dentro de un elemento en línea, por lo que:

```
<div>Este uso de <span>texto que <div>quiero</div> marcar incluyendo etiquetas de este modo se considera</span> inadecuado</div>
```

A partir de HTML5, algunos elementos de bloque se pueden colocar dentro de algunos elementos en línea. Consulte la referencia de [MDN aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories) para obtener una lista bastante clara de este tipo de casuísticas. Los ejemplos anteriores siguen siendo ilegales/incorreectos, ya que  solo acepta contenido de frases y  es contenido de flujo.

Un correcto ejemplo de uso es el siguiente:

```css
h1 a {text-decoration:none; font-size:16px;}
span.textodecorado {color:orange; text-decoration:underline; font-size:23px;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="userspace">
    Hola, <span class="username">Nombre Apellido</span> |
    <a href="#">Perfil</a> |
    <a href="#">Documentación</a>
  </div>
  <h1><a href="#">Enlace relevante <span class="textodecorado">TEXTO DECORADO</span></a></h1>
</div>
```

Comparto la información que encontré de gran ayuda en una [respuesta a esta pregunta en la versión en inglés de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-div-and-span-elements) por su clara explicación respecto a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

## Etiqueta div:

La etiqueta `<div>` hace parte de los elementos HTML de bloque, es decir, va a ocupar todo el ancho del documento disponible. Si no la usas con hojas de estilos el navegador no mostrará nada especial al crear la división.

##### Un breve ejemplo:

Su uso para divisiones es bastante sencillo y va a manejar la siguiente estructura:

```css
div {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Ejemplo de cómo funcionaría; la etiqueta div para divisiones.</p>
 <p>Puedes insertar el contenido que necesites.</p>
 <p>Esta sería la última línea de nuestro texto.</p>
</div>
```

---

## Etiqueta span:

La etiqueta `<span>` hace parte de los elementos en HTML que se conocen por ser **en línea**. Al contrario de los elementos en bloque, estos sólo hacen uso del espacio que ocupan.

##### Un breve ejemplo:

Al igual que con `<div>`, esta etiqueta va a manejar la siguiente estructura:

```css
div {
 background-color: yellow;
}

span {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Ejemplo de <span>cómo funcionaría</span>; la etiqueta div para divisiones.</p>
 <p>Puedes <span>insertar el contenido</span> que necesites.</p>
 <p>Esta sería <span>la última línea</span> de nuestro texto.</p>
</div>
```

---

## ¿En qué se diferencian?:

Las etiquetas `<div>` y `<span>` en HTML son similares, ya que son etiquetas sin sentido semántico que sirven para separar elementos e insertar distintos estilos bajo una misma categoría. La diferencia entre estas dos etiquetas es que `<span>` **se utiliza para elementos en línea, no en bloque**. Esta etiqueta puede usarse cuando queremos que una parte del texto tenga un estilo diferente, pero no queremos usar énfasis o `<strong>`.

---

## Conclusiones:

- Las etiquetas `<div>` y `<span>`, no tienen ningún tipo de significado especial, solo que la primera se define como un elemento de bloque y por tanto el navegador mostrara un salto de línea antes y después de la misma, mientras que la segunda es un elemento de línea.
- Cuando se utilizan actualmente en un documento web, se pueden utilizar para establecer opciones de formato mediante hojas de estilo a bloques completos o elementos individuales del documento.

---

> *Fuente de investigación: [¿Cómo funcionan las etiquetas div y span en HTML?](https://keepcoding.io/blog/como-funcionan-las-etiquetas-div-y-span-en-html/)*